# Change of ID of an ASP Controller from "Test" to "MainContent_Test"

Tags: asp.net

If I have a `TABLE` or a `DROPDOWNLIST`, with an `ID="Test"`, in a Page `Default.aspx`, contained in a `Master Page`, these controllers change their ID's to `"MainContent_Test"`, means any CSS attributed to `#Test` won't work, and I feel that I'm having problems in `C#` as well, why does this happen? and How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET adds name of control containers to generated client ID. But if you use .NET 4.0 or later you can use cotntrol's `ClientIdMode` property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.100).aspx

Just set it to `Static` and the ID will not change.

Other options may include defining style via class and not attaching it to specific control ID.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using asp.net 4 and above you can set the ClientIdMode of the control
This will ensure that it won't change and can be assessed via css.

```
<asp:DropDownList ClientIdMode="Static" ID="Test" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Shiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiit looks like I'm gonna change this for all controllers, thanks :D